# Using Kleene Star to define set of all tuples?

Tags: formal-languages

How is a set $S$ of all the ordered tuples with elements from [universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)) $\mathbb U$ defined?  For instance, $S = \{(), (x), (x,y), (x, (x,y))...\} \land x,y \in \mathbb U$.  Is the Kleene Star function composed $n$ times and summed $S =\cup_{i=1}^\infty \star^{(i)} (\mathbb U)$ the solution?  If not, what is?

Comment: What is your definition of an ordered tuple? Should $S$ also include $(y)$ and $(y,x)$? What about $(x, x)$ and $(x, y, x)$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin an ordered tuple is the cartesian product of sets $X_1 \times ... \times X_n$ which is defined as a function indexed by $\mathbb N$.  Yes and Yes.